# Организация внешнего вида сайта

Tags: php, html5, laravel

Всем доброго времени суток господа. Разрабатываю сайт на Laravel. Есть зарегистрированные и незарегистрированные пользователи. Для первых добавляются некие фичи в виде ссылок в шапке сайта. Вся шапка поключается так.

```
@extends("layouts/header_footer")

@section("header")
@parent
@endsection



@section("footer")
@parent
@endsection
```

Как мне в header передать переменную $user. В самом шаблоне проверять сессию не охота да и не по mvc-шовски. Или у кого какие есть варианты для вынесения шапки в отдельный файл. Всем благодарен за помощь и идеи.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вынесите всё что нужно в отдельный файл и подключите через @include.
Или вопрос в том, чтобы глобально передать переменную?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar
Вы совершенно правы, нужно глобально передать переменную. С контроллера я её передаю в вид, который подтягивает шапку. Вот в шапку мне и нужно передать переменную.

Comment: Разве что разбить шапку и футер на два разных файла и вызвать через view->render(); ибо шаблонизатор пока бессилен.

Answer (score 0):

Если не критично, что выводиться переменная может во всех представлениях, то можно создать сервис-провайдер (название может быть любым, взял View).

```
php artisan make:provider ViewServiceProvider
```

И в метод boot:

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->first();
    view()->share('user', $user);
}
```

В представлении, соответственно, проверяйте, кому что отдаёте через:

```
@auth
    Для авторизированных, например, $user->name
@endauth
    Для мимо проходящих
@guest
@endguest
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, позже испытаю.